# What is the difference between ROS and OES onboard SDK's?

Tags: dji-sdk

I am just getting into drone programing and I want to use my Jetson tx2 to control my Matrice 100. I noticed that there were two sdks that could be installed, ROS and OES.

What is the difference between the two?

Which one is recommended to be installed on a Jetson for autonomy?

Answer (score 0):

To clear up some confusion regarding this - we offer a single SDK on Linux, the DJI Onboard SDK (OSDK). For convenience, we offer a ROS wrapper around the SDK that is compliant with ROS standards. Your Jetson TX2 should be able to run either the SDK by itself, or its ROS wrapper based on what your needs are - use ROS if you want to interface with existing ROS packages and use ROS tools, or use the SDK by itself if you need to create efficient and purpose-built applications. All of the sample code documented [here](http://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/sample-doc/sample-setup.html) and available on GitHub ([Onboard-SDK](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK) and [Onboard-SDK-ROS](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS)) is functionally equivalent on both platforms.

Further reading:

1. DJI OSDK Doc - http://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/introduction/homepage.html
2. Quick Start - Run a C++/Linux sample application
3. ROS Wiki - http://wiki.ros.org/dji_sdk